# Why does Clojure's atom swap! return the new value?

Tags: clojure

Most atom operators return the previous value before the swap such as `std::atomic::fetch_add` in C++. It's natural to use atomic int as a global increasing id starting from 0. Why does Clojure's atom return the value which is swapped in?

```
(def global-counter (atom 0))
(defn next! [] (dec (swap! global-counter inc)))
```

Is there a better way to create a zero-based counter in Clojure?

Comment: `(def global-counter (atom -1))` and get rid of `dec` call ?

Comment: @hsestupin it won't work for unsigned int which doesn't exist in java anyway :)

Comment: ok, look at my answer below. AtomicInteger is faster then clojure atoms and looks more idiomatic and more suitable for your case.

Comment: Thanks! I also wanted to understand the reason behind this decision to return previous value in Clojure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`swap!` allows you to apply an arbitrary function to the atom, and you don't know in advance what the result will be. If `swap!` didn't give you the post value it would be less useful; you'd have to create a transaction to deref it if you wanted to know the result (or someone could update it before you deref'ed it).

Comment: `swap!` doesn't allow side effects of `fn`. If it simply returns the previous value, I will be able to do `(fn old-val)` for the new value. I know it's less optimal to run the `fn` twice here.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441638/alternate-version-of-swap-also-returning-swapped-out-value

Comment: This is simply not true. If `swap!` returned the pre-transaction value, you could as well construct the result by invoking the in-transaction application as I illustrated in my example. It would be even more useful to somebody interested in the post-transaction value as `swap!` is useful to somebody interested in the pre transaction value because sometimes you can't recreate the pre-transaction value while you can always create the post-transaction value. Derefing is not relevant to the question, too.

Answer (score 3):

Counter question: Do you know why `std::atomic::fetch_add` returns the pre-transaction value? (I don't.)

Calling `swap!` peforms a transaction and returns its result. In a concurrent scenario, if it returned the pre-transaction value, the only deterministic way to get the transaction result would be to repeat the in-transaction application, e. g.

```
(def pre-tx (std-swap! global-counter inc))
(def tx-result (inc pre-tx))
```

Certainly, an opposite example could be made up for the pre-transaction value. However, in most cases (and your example case too - see below), the tx-result is the value relevant for further reference. This is why `swap!` was designed to return it directly. For different requirements, a `ref` is suitable (Unless using an `atom` is requirement, in which case you have to create your own spin-loop with `compare-and-set!`).

In your example,`next!` should return `1` on the first call and there is no reason to `dec` it as long as **counting** is the given example. Counting always starts with one: If you count one, your total count is `1`. If `next!` ever returned `0` (imaginary) `last!` would return `-1`, an invalid total count.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` for the purpose of creating global increasing id:

```
(def global-counter (AtomicInteger. 0))
(defn next! [] (.getAndIncrement global-counter))
```