# How do I split an atom in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a set which is stored in an atom, like so

```
(def numbers (atom #{1 2 3 4 5}))
```

Numbers are atomically added and removed from this set regularly using `swap!`. In a separate thread, I would like to have a function that extracts and remove the even numbers from the set and returns them.

One way I could do this would look something like:

```
(let [{even true odd false} (group-by even? @numbers)]
  (reset! numbers odd)
  even)
```

However, this isn't an atomic operation. `numbers` could change between the `group-by` and `reset!`. Is there a way to perform this operation atomically?

Comment: Generally speaking, having your code doing logic (such as splitting content across) be impure (and any code that knows about reference types rather than dealing only in data is definitely impure) is a smell.

Answer (score 6):

The function applied by `swap!` does not need to be atomic. You should be able to do this using `swap!`.

If you want to leave just the odd numbers and get back the even numbers, you can have the function applied by `swap!` return just the odds, and then that's what the atom's value will be updated to.

The remaining question is how to get back the even numbers. There are lots of ways you could do this—I'm not sure what would be the best. Maybe you could use the metadata on your collection? Something like this:

```
(def numbers (atom #{1 2 3 4 5}))

(defn atom-splitter [xs]
  (let [{even true odd false} (group-by even? xs)]
    (with-meta (set odd) {:evens (set even)})))

(swap! numbers atom-splitter)
```

The value of `@numbers` is then `#{1 3 5}`.

The value of `(meta @numbers)` is `{:evens #{2 4}}`.

Since `swap!` returns the swapped-in value, you can be sure the metadata on the returned value contains the other half of your split collection. For example, the following would be safe:

```
(defn split-off-evens [a]
  (-> (swap! numbers atom-splitter) meta :evens))
```

Calling `(split-off-evens numbers)` returns `#{2 4}` if `numbers` has its original value. Since this is still a correct use of an `atom`, you can assume that Clojure handles all the thread-safety issues.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the idiomatic way to maintain atomicity is to use transactions:

```
(def numbers (ref #{1 2 3 4 5}))
(future (loop []
          (Thread/sleep 10)
          (dosync
           (alter numbers conj (rand-int 1000)))
          (recur)))

(dosync
 (let [{even true odd false} (group-by even? @numbers)]
   (ref-set numbers odd)
   even))
```

For more see: http://clojure.org/refs.

*EDIT*

If you really want to use atoms, then this will work:

```
(def numbers (atom #{1 2 3 4 5}))
(future (loop []
          (Thread/sleep 10)
          (swap! numbers conj (rand-int 1000)))
          (recur))

(loop []
  (let [val @numbers
        {even true odd false} (group-by even? val)]
    (if (compare-and-set! numbers val odd)
      even
      (recur))))
```

Comment: I don't think this is idiomatic. You use refs to coordinate when you need _multiple_ consistent updates. However, in this case there's still only one atom being updated.

Comment: Refs are also appropriate when you need read-modify-write semantics. However it can be done using atoms. Please see updated post.

Comment: Yes, refs *can* give you a safe way to do read-modify-write operations, but that doesn't mean you should use them when the existing atom operations do the job just fine. I like your new solution much better. You've basically just [implemented a custom `swap!`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15442107/1427124). I think I might prefer that approach to using collection metadata.

Comment: I like your solution; nice way to think outside the box using metadata. :)

Comment: Interesting compare-and-set! solution. I like this, but couldn't you end up in an infinite loop?

Also, thanks, I'll need to look more into refs.

Comment: My code for atoms is just explicitly doing what Clojure is doing behind the scenes when you use `swap!`. See `(clojure.repl/source swap!)` and [Atom.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Atom.java). So no, you won't get an infinite loop.

Comment: @DevonPeticolas - Yes, you can end up with an infinite loop—but the same goes with using `swap!`. Clojure's atoms don't have any fairness guarantees. However, if one thread is starving (keeps failing the `compare-and-swap!`), then that means some other thread is making progress (it updated the atom). This type of progress guarantee is usually considered acceptable. If that turns out to be a problem then you might need to look at something other than atoms.

Comment: @DaoWen - Exactly. I just thought this was obvious. I should have worded it differently from "you won't get an infinite loop"; sorry for not pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile in 2021 (since 1.9) you can use `swap-vals!` which atomically returns both the old and new values, so of course the evens is just the difference between them:

```
(apply clojure.set/difference
       (swap-vals! numbers
                   #(into #{} (filter odd? %))))
```